# I have multiple buttons but don't want them to submit the form

Tags: html

I have a Html.BeginForm with 3 buttons inside of it; the submit button (which should submit the form) and two other buttons, which are actually toggles, but they keep submitting my form.  Any ideas?

Comment: My crystal ball is in the shop today. Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want one button to submit the form, Why do you keep more than one submit buttons in the form, Change those to normal buttons/ anchor tag as needed.

If you still want to keep all those submit buttons, you can apply a css class to the other buttons and prevent the form submit in javascript

```
<input type="submit" class="nonSubmit" value="Button1" />
<input type="submit" class="nonSubmit" value="Button2" />
<input type="submit" value="Real Submit" />
```

and the script is (using jQuery)

```
$(function(){

   $("input.nonSubmit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   });

});
```